# Overwrite Std.string

Tags: haxe

is it possible to overwrite how an Std.string transforms an object into a string?

E.g. I have a class Person.

```
class Person {
    public var name:String;
}
```

However when I use:

```
var p:Person = new Person("Some name");
trace(Std.string(p)); // this will return something like foo.Person( bar )
```

but I want to have something like:

```
var p:Person = new Person("Some name");
trace(Std.string(p)); // should return "Person(Some name)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `toString()` method to your class.

Example: https://try.haxe.org/#F7A77

It will work with `Std.string()` but may not work with runtime `toString()`. The trick *does* work at runtime for javascript target, **but** the `toString()` method will be removed by dce ([1](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-dce.html)).

You can either disable dce (I would not recommend it for javascript target) or just force the compiler to keep your `toString()` function by adding a `@:keep` meta:

```
@:keep
function toString() {
    return "my object";
}
```

Comment: The `@:keep` meta is an important bit, I was wondering why my `toString` was not in the compiled class, thought it could be the DCE and indeed it was

Answer (score -1):

You may overwrite Std.toString by implementing a method that returns a string and annotate it with "@:to". Example:

```
class Person {
    public var name:String;
    public function new(s:String) {
        name = s;
    }
    @:to
    public inline function toString():String {
        return "Person(" + name + ")";
    }
}

class Test {
    static function main() {
        var p:Person = new Person("SomeName");
        trace(Std.string(p));
    }
}
```

Comment: `@:to` does absolutely nothing here, it's for implicit conversion methods on abstracts. Also, `trace(Std.string(p))` is redundant / the same as `trace(p)`.

Comment: `trace(Std.string(p))` is not exactly the same as `trace(p)`. The former resolves `toString()` at runtime while the latter at compile time.

Comment: It's still redundant / leads to the same end result, and I would consider it bad practice to explicitly use `Std.string()` in a `trace`.

Comment: I always prefer doing things at compile time; if it saves a bit of resources at runtime I consider it a good thing.

As for this particular example, `Std.string()` is more powerful than runtime `toString()` because it is haxe code aware, which allows things like the "toString" magic which is needed by this question.